# Materialize - Change select option text with js / jquery

Tags: text, html-select, materialize

I'm using Materialize and try to change the options's text via js/jquery for multilingual use.

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected data-translation="languageselect"></option>
    <option values="en-GB">English (en-GB)</option>
    <option values="de">Deutsch (de)</option>
</select>
```

I translate all objects containing the data-translation attribute via JS (using innerHTML).

So the translation script is something like (and it works)

```
translationObject.innerHTML = translation
```

But now I'm using Materialize and have a problem with the options texts. The translated text is not displayed - first I call my translation function and then the initialization of the select element.

```
$('select').formSelect();
```

Anyone an idea?